# Compiler doesn't see associates type is the same as concrete type

Tags: rust, associated-types

I have a little nuisance in my project, that I can't resolve: The compiler doesn't see that the associated type is the same as the concrete type and won't let my do an assignement.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=26bfae60b0ca52a902eaa664ca9b416d)

Does anyone know how to fix it. Thank you for taking your time.

Artos

```
// This program fails to compile 
// Compiler doesn't see that the associated type and type of user id are the same. 
struct User {
    pub id: u64,
}

trait KeyTrait {
    type Key;
    fn key(&self) -> Self::Key;
}

impl KeyTrait for User {
    type Key = u64;
    fn key(&self) -> Self::Key {
        self.id
    }
}

trait PrintTrait {
    fn print_key<K: KeyTrait>(key: K);
}

impl PrintTrait for User {
    fn print_key<K: KeyTrait>(key_impl: K) {
        let id: u64 = key_impl.key(); // Raises error: expected u64, found associated type

        println!("Found key {}", id);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let user = User { id: 5 };
    User::print_key(user);
}
```

Comment: In your case `key_impl` is  actually a `User` , instead of generic parameter you might want to use `&self` to infer the associated type. Here is an [implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f60f95fb37171d83df0bba4fac54b81f)

Comment: Otherwise you need to provide associated type explicitly, here is an [implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11ce65803bc5c349eac945ef1369f9e8) without `&self`

Comment: I tried the explicit version, but have failed for 1.5h. `&self` however works in my project.
Thank you Ömer for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code makes the assumption that *every* implementation of `KeyTrait` has the same associated `Key` type.

```
impl PrintTrait for User {
    fn print_key<K: KeyTrait>(key_impl: K) {
        let id: u64 = key_impl.key();
        println!("Found key {}", id);
    }
}
```

In fact, an implementation of `KeyTrait` could choose any type.

You can encode this assumption in the type system:

```
trait PrintTrait {
    fn print_key<K>(key: K)
    where
        K: KeyTrait<Key = u64>;
}

impl PrintTrait for User {
    fn print_key<K>(key_impl: K) 
    where
        K: KeyTrait<Key = u64>,
    {
        let id: u64 = key_impl.key();
    }
}
```

Or, if you need `PrintTrait` to be generic over all possible associated `Key` types:

```
trait PrintTrait<T> {
    fn print_key<K>(key: K)
    where
        K: KeyTrait<Key = T>;
}

impl PrintTrait<u64> for User {
    fn print_key<K>(key_impl: K) 
    where
        K: KeyTrait<Key = u64>,
    {
        let id: u64 = key_impl.key();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for your clear explanation. Now I not only have a working solution from Ömer, but I even understand what's going on in my code :). Have to admit generics in Rust sometimes crank my brain.